# How do I customise the style of the Auth0 lock control?

Tags: css, less, auth0

I am trying to style the Auth0 lock control, however my styles are not being applied.

According to the documentation I should be able to style this control to match my website, [Lock: Customize the look and feel](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/ui-customization).

> Prepend a body key in front of the customization CSS in order to win
>   in CSS specification

I have added this line to my Less style sheet.

```
body #a0-lock.a0-theme-default .a0-panel {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

However my style is not applied, and when I debug the style sheet in Firefox I can see my code is loosing the selection.

[image]

How can I win the style selection? How can I style the Auth0 lock control?

*If its important I'm running an ASP.Net MVC website where my Less is converted to CSS. I am using version 8.2 of Auth0 lock.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve using a more specific selector. In my question I had missed out the full selector (`*`)

So; `body #a0-lock.a0-theme-default .a0-panel` became; `body #a0-lock.a0-theme-default .a0-panel *`

I found the easiest way to get the the full selector was by debugging the styles on the the running application.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your order of css is also defined correctly. According to [order of css definition docs](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/ui-customization#order-of-definition)

> Auth0 Lock inserts it's CSS definitions in the head node of the HTML
>   Document and it does this at the very end. So, in order to override
>   the Lock's main styles you must insert your CSS in the body node,
>   right after the  tag definition for the Auth0 Lock inclusion:

This worked for me

```
<script src="http://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-7.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css"/>
```

then in my css

```
body #a0-lock.a0-theme-default .a0-panel {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

For changing font-family of individual elements use more specific selectors. For eg. to change font-family of lock header use following

```
body #a0-lock.a0-theme-default .a0-header h1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans' !important;
}
```

To change all panel element font-family use `*` like below

```
body #a0-lock.a0-theme-default .a0-panel * {
    font-family: 'Open Sans' !important;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but it didnt help.

Comment: what didn't work? the background color change to `greenyellow` or the font-family change to `Open Sans`? In the later case, use more specific selector for example to change font-family of auth0 lock header add `a0-header h1` selector. For changing font-family of all panel elements add `*` in the end of your selector. See my edit above.

Comment: The order of the CSS definition didn't seem to have much of an affect.